# How to solve Angular 504 Error Response coming from backend layer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have angular application on my localhost(http) and a spring boot application on localhost(https). The proxy have been configured in angular to access spring boot APIs but getting 504 error while calling backend api from angular. I also tried using proxy.conf.json to create proxy to backend layer but didnt work.
Appreciate your help

```html
 proxy-config.js-->

    const fs = require("fs");
    const PROXY_CONFIG = {
      "/api/*": {
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        target: {
          host: "127.0.0.1:8080",
          passphrase: 'xxxx',
          pfx: fs.readFileSync('./applicationcert.pfx'),
          protocol: "https:"
        }
      }
    };
    module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;


Sercice.js-->
 this.httpClient.request('GET', '/api/v1', options).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  },error => {
    console.log(error);
},
() => {
    console.log("Subscribed Else");
});

package.json--> 
    "start": "ng serve --host 127.0.0.1 --proxy-config proxy-config.js",
```

Comment: wich version of angular are you using?

Comment: Using NPM 10 version.

Comment: Thanks for your response but your localhost is http, however I have configured https on my local instead http. As Https required Certificate then it will not work the one posted above

Answer (score 0):

in my angular project, i have integrated the proxy.conf in this way:

on angular.json

```js
"serve": {
  ....
  "options": {
    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json",
   },
```

and my proxy.conf.json

```js
{
  "/path/to/api/*": { // with * i can intercept all the api that start wit this url
    "target": "http://localhost:8881", //this is the target where  angular redirect api calls
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  },
```

[here](https://angular.io/guide/build) you can find more information

Comment: Thanks for your response but your localhost is http, however I have configured https on my local instead http. As Https required Certificate then it will not work the one posted above